# Primefaces schedule and selectEvent

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, schedule

I use 5.0 now, but in 4.0 is do the same. With 3.5 works well.

I've got a ScheduleEvent implementation, that I store in postgreSQL table with jpa.
I use lazy data model, so I can persist new events, and load them back. Event and title is appear in schedult.

ScheduleManager is a session scoped bean, where I handle ajax events, like onEventMove, onEventResize, and onEventSelect.
The last event handler getObject method give back null, so I can't edit event.

My event implementation like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "basescheduleevent")
@NamedQuery(name = "BaseScheduleEvent.findAll", query = "SELECT l FROM BaseScheduleEvent l")
public class BaseScheduleEvent implements ScheduleEvent, Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6213082779383114637L;

  private String id;
  private String title;
  private Object data;
  private Date startDate;
  private Date endDate;
  private String description;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
   public String getId() {
      return this.id;
   }

   public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   @Lob
   @Override
   public Object getData() {
      return this.data;
   }

   public void setData(Object data) {
      this.data = data;
   }
...
```

and handler method like this:

```
   public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
      ScheduleEvent event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();
      if (event != null) {
         EventHistory eventHistory = (EventHistory) event.getData();
         Subject subject = eventHistory.getSubject();
      }
   }
```

And here is the xhtml schedule:

```
<h:form id="ScheduleForm">
     <p:schedule style="width:100%;height:100%" view="month" id="schedule" widgetVar="scheduleWidget"
        timeZone="Europe/Budapest" widgetVar="scheduleWidget" locale="hu"
        value="#{scheduleManager.eventModel}"
        binding="#{scheduleManager.schedule}">
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect"
           listener="#{scheduleManager.onDateSelect}" update=":timerForm"
           oncomplete="PF('timerDialogWidget').show();" />
        <p:ajax event="eventSelect"
           listener="#{scheduleManager.onEventSelect}" update=":timerForm"
           oncomplete="PF('timerDialogWidget').show();" />
        <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{scheduleManager.onEventMove}" />
        <p:ajax event="eventResize"
           listener="#{scheduleManager.onEventResize}" />
     </p:schedule>
</h:form>
```

So I googled around for solution, but I can't find solution. I found allways old primeface event handlers, and solutions.

Move and resize have null pointer exception before event handler.

Please let me know the solution.

I put a clean method call to load method to SessionScoped bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ScheduleManager implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 620934289508314544L;

   private BaseScheduleEvent currentEvent;

   private ScheduleModel lazyEventModel;

   @Inject
   private UserService userService;

   @Inject
   private ScheduleService scheduleService;

   public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
      lazyEventModel = new LazyScheduleModel() {

         private static final long serialVersionUID = -7030798462691388329L;

         public void loadEvents(Date start, Date end) {

            final TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Budapest");
            List<ScheduleEvent> eventList = scheduleService.loadEvents(
                  start, end, timeZone);
            clear();
            for (ScheduleEvent event : eventList) {
               addEvent(event);
            }
         }
      };
      return lazyEventModel;
   }
```

In Schedule.java I found something that may help find the problem. An id missing.

```
    else if(eventName.equals("eventSelect")) {
        String selectedEventId = params.get(clientId + "_selectedEventId");
    ScheduleEvent selectedEvent = this.getValue().getEvent(selectedEventId);

        wrapperEvent = new SelectEvent(this, behaviorEvent.getBehavior(), selectedEvent);
```

this.getValue().getEvent() give back null (getValue event ArrayList.size = 0, and this why selectedEvent is null).
But this run after persist the object, and event has id, I confirmed at database. Events load back to scheduler, I see the events in the view. When I load back events, each has id value.

In DefaultScheduleModel at public ScheduleEvent getEvent(String id) the id parameter get
"e3fdce6b-8f4b-4b41-b6f4-19c0a9496e63" value and the (ArrayList)events.size = 0 at for loop (ScheduleEvent event : events)
But each time when I check id at SessionScoped bean methods the id is null.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is much easier. Just add a check for null.

```
 public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
  if (lazyEventModel == null) {
     lazyEventModel = new LazyScheduleModel() {
```